# VB -When a compiler compiles the code, does it include the libraries that were imported?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, import

I'm really sorry about this basic question but I couldn't find anything on MSDN except an overview of the import function. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I've imported the System and System.IO libraries. I'm wondering if this would make the program unusable if they didn't have the libraries preloaded on their machine or if the compiler actually includes the files needed so the application is truly standalone. Thank you!

Comment: They are namespaces, not libraries.  It is not possible to create a standalone desktop app, the .NET Framework is always required.  Which includes the necessary assemblies with those namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System` and `System.IO` are part of the Microsoft .NET Framework.  Without the Framework, your program won't execute at all.  Most modern Windows machines already have some version of the Framework installed.